# (Done) Reopen question on coworkers not using ticketing system

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

The question [Annoying phone calls from coworkers who don't use our ticketing system](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113963/annoying-phone-calls-from-coworkers-who-dont-use-our-ticketing-system) was recently closed, with votes both because it is company-specific and that it requires an addressable goal.

I don't believe that either of these close reasons apply here. The question states that the company has a ticketing system and people aren't using it. The question is then *how* to get people to use it, which is completely answerable. I did reword the final question after some people had already voted, so their reasoning may not apply anymore.

There are a couple similar questions out there ([How can I convince my colleague to call the help desk instead of contacting me directly?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/110137/how-can-i-convince-my-colleague-to-call-the-help-desk-instead-of-contacting-me-d)) so this type of question is on-topic. I also don't think this is a duplicate because the linked question really focuses more on the personal conflict between two employees, not on people simply trying to sidestep the process.

**I would like to request that this question be reopened.**

Comment: I agree completely VTRO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question has been reopened now after a small edit.